# can not change $scope variables value in some cases using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, monaca

I am using angularjs with Monaca to build mobile application
I use this part for login process

```
$scope.login = function(username, password){
        $scope.isLogging = true;
        $scope.loginMsge = '';
        service.getUsernamePassword(username, password).then(function (response) { // try to connect to server data base
            if(typeof response == 'undefined'){ // there is no internet so check user and password from local data base
                console.log('local login');
                var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0" , "TestDatabase" , 200000);
                db.transaction(function(transaction) {
                    transaction.executeSql("SELECT * FROM user_t WHERE username = ?;", [username], function(transaction, result) {
                        if (result.rows.length > 0) {
                            if(bcrypt.compareSync(password, result.rows[0].password) == true){
                                $scope.userLogin = true;
                                $scope.getProjects();// get projects to display them after login
                                myNav.pushPage('home.html')
                                $scope.isLogging = false;
                                console.log('login');
                            }else{ // user name and password is invalid
                                $scope.userLogin = false;
                                $scope.getProjects();// there is no need to this call here but the loginMsge will not displayed if I didn't do that
                                $scope.loginMsge = 'Invalid username and password';
                                $scope.isLogging = false;
                            }
                        }else{ // the user is not exist in data base
                            $scope.userLogin = false;
                            $scope.getProjects();
                            $scope.loginMsge = 'Invalid username and password ';
                            $scope.isLogging = false;
                        }
                    }, function(transaction, error) {
                        console.log('log failed '+error);
                    });
                });
            }else if(response.data.userLogin){
                console.log('Server login');
                $scope.userLogin = true;
                $scope.getProjects();
                myNav.pushPage('home.html');
                $scope.isLogging = false;
            }else{
                $scope.userLogin = false;
                $scope.loginMsge = 'Invalid username and password ';
                $scope.isLogging = false;
            }
        });
    }
```

first I try to connect to server database to check username and password and if application couldn't connect (no internet) I check user name and password in local database

if the user name and password is invalid I want to

```
$scope.userLogin = false;
 $scope.getProjects();// there is no need to this call here but the loginMsge will not displayed if I didn't do that
 $scope.loginMsge = 'Invalid username and password';
 $scope.isLogging = false;
```

and if the user name and password is correct I want to to do the following

```
 $scope.userLogin = true; // I know that user is successfully login
 $scope.getProjects();// get projects to display them after login
 myNav.pushPage('home.html')
 $scope.isLogging = false;// use this variable to display and hide circular progress
```

the problem that if I didn't call the function getProjects() the message will not display and the scope variables will not work

the function $scope.getProjects in my controller

```
$scope.getProjects = function(){
        localDBService.getProjects().then(function(result) {
            $scope.projects = result;
        });
    }
```

the function getProjects() in localDBService

```
 function getProjects() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var projects;
        var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "TestDatabase", 200000);
        db.transaction(function(transaction) {
            transaction.executeSql("SELECT * FROM projects_t;", [], function(transaction, result) {
                if (result.rows.length > 0) {
                        deferred.resolve(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result.rows)));
                }
                // deferred.resolve(result);
            }, function(transaction, error) {
                deferred.reject(error);
            });
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    };
```

UPDATE: this is my view

```
<ons-template id="login.html">
    <ons-navigator var="myNav">
        <ons-page>
            <ons-toolbar>
                <div class="left"></div>
                <div class="center">Log In</div>
                <div class="right"></div>
            </ons-toolbar>
            <ons-toolbar>
                <div class="center">Login Page</div>
            </ons-toolbar>

            <div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 30px;">
                <p>
                    <ons-input id="username" ng-model="username" modifier="underbar" placeholder="Username" float ng-model="page.username"></ons-input>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <ons-input id="password" ng-model="password" modifier="underbar" type="password" placeholder="Password" float ng-model="page.password"></ons-input>
                </p>
                <div style="display: table;margin: 0 auto; "><ons-progress-circular indeterminate ng-show="isLogging" ></ons-progress-circular></div>
                <p style="margin-top: 30px;">
                    <ons-button ng-click="login(username,password)">Sign in</ons-button>
                </p>
                <div style ="text-align:center; color: red;" >{{loginMsge}}</div>
            </div>

        </ons-page>
        <ons-modal var="modal_loading_login">
            <ons-icon icon="ion-loading-c" spin="true" ></ons-icon>
        </ons-modal>
</ons-template>
```

Comment: Is it a problem with the variables not changing or not displaying the change on the browser ? If you `console.log $scope.loginMsge;` after you changed it, does it have the old or new value ?

If it has changed but is not displayed, this may be an issue with your variable not triggering a re-render on the $scope. You can try `$scope.apply()` instead of your function call and see if it works.

Comment: you are right, the problem with display not with values, when I add the following code  console.log('$scope.userLogin '+$scope.userLogin);
                                console.log('$scope.isLogging '+$scope.isLogging);
                                $scope.apply(); I find that the variable values is changed but I get this error  "Uncaught TypeError: $scope.apply is not a function"

Comment: For async processes use `$scope.apply()` updating scopped data.

Comment: the problem is disappear when I added $scope.$apply() not $scope.apply()

Comment: @groooves add an answer so I can mark it as accepted,  thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably an issue with your variable not triggering a re-render on the `$scope`. Use `$scope.$apply()` instead of your function call and it should work.